# Problem with strip, replace functions in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, strip

I am trying to strip all the special characters from a pandas dataframe column of words with the split() and replace() functions.

Howerver, it does not  work. The special characters are not stripped from the words.

Can somebody enlight me please ?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("2022-12-08_word_selection.csv")

for n in df.index:
    i = str(df.loc[n, "words"])
    if len(i) > 12:
        df.loc[n, "words"] = ""
df["words"] = df["words"].str.replace("$", "s")
df["words"] = df["words"].str.strip('[,:."*+-#/\^`@}{~&%â€™àáâæ¢ß¥£™©®ª×÷±²³¼½¾µ¿¶·¸º°¯§…¤¦≠¬ˆ¨‰øœšÞùúûý€')
df["words"] = df["words"].str.strip("\n")
df = df.groupby(["words"]).mean()

print(df)
```

Firstly, the program replaces all words in the "words" column longer than 12 characters. Then , I was hoping it would strip all the special characters from the "words" column.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the data and the matching expected output. `strip` is only removing characters at the extremities of the string, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid using a loop and instead use `transform()` to replace words longer than 12 characters with an empty string. Second, the `Series.str` conversion is not necessary prior to calling `replace()`. Third, `split()` only removes leading and trailing characters so it is not what you want. Use a regular expression with `replace()` instead. Finally, to remove special characters, it is cleaner to use a regex negative set to match and remove only the characters that are not letters or numbers. This looks like: `"[^A-Za-z0-9]"`.

Here is some example data and code that works:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "words": [
            123,
            "abcd",
            "efgh",
            "abcdefghijklmn",
            "lol%",
            "Hornbæk",
            "10:03",
            "$999¼",
        ]
    }
)
# Faster and more concise than a loop
df["words"] = df["words"].transform(lambda x: "" if len(x) > 12 else x)
# Not sure why you do this but okay
df["words"] = df["words"].replace("$", "s")
# Use a regex negative set to keep only letters and numbers
df["words"] = df["words"].replace(re.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]"), "")
display(df)
```

outputs:

```
    words
0   123
1   abcd
2   efgh
3   abcdefghijklmn
4   lol
5   Hornbk
6   1003
7   999
```